# Why Excel Services does not keep pivot chart style when date changes?

Tags: sharepoint, excel, sharepoint-2010

I'm experiencing a problem with Excel Services and charts:

If in my excel pivot chart I use the default style, when publishing the excel to sharepoint all goes well. When I try to make some customization on the pivot chart (e.g. add data labels) they are kept unless the pivot data is updated adding a new row.

Specifically, I have pivot data with dates as rows and the filter is saved on "Today". When the day change, my chart style is lost (reverted to the default one).

Does anyone know about this odd behavior? Is there some setting in excel or Excel Service I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can't add Excel-Services tag :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In client Excel, refreshing the pivot table often reverts formatting of the table and related chart to the default. Microsoft doesn't quite admit it's a bug, but suggests recording a macro when you reformat your chart, so you can rerun the macro. I suppose this doesn't help in Excel Services.

Comment: Yes, it's very sad! For excel services the thing would be more painful. Do you think is possible to schedule a silent macro run on the background daily? May be using powershel...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem when I tried to make my data labels vertical. I found that you could prevent it from happening if you saved your chart design as a template. So the steps for the workaround are
1. Style the chart as you want it to look.
2. Go to the Design tab of the PivotChart Tools group. 
3. Hit the 2nd button to the left labeled Save as Template
4. Save the template, the name and the location don't seem to matter.
5. Then save back to sharepoint, now your style will stay even as you save.